# Why openzeppeling use require instead of cursom errors?

Tags: solidity, require, custom-errors

As far as I know custom errors are more gas efficient but for example the openzeppelin contracts still use require instead of custom errors

[ERC20.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol)

```
function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
    address owner = _msgSender();
    uint256 currentAllowance = allowance(owner, spender);
    require(currentAllowance >= subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero");
    unchecked {
        _approve(owner, spender, currentAllowance - subtractedValue);
    }

    return true;
}
```

so my question is: Why openzeppelin use require instead of custom errors?

Comment: Apparently it's on the roadmap https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/issues/3614